# Vue Test Utils - Skip created hook

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I want to skip all of the methods that are being called within the `created()` hook. Is there a way to do this?

So instead of this

```
        created() {
            this.getAllocations();
            this.getModels();
            this.getTeams();
            this.getCustodians();
            this.getDefaultFeeStructure();
        }
```

I want this

```
created() { }
```

It's worth noting, I cannot actually change the component itself, but for testing purposes, this needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a global mixin (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin)

However, for your case you need a custom merge strategy to prevent the created hook on the component from being run:

> Hook functions with the same name are merged into an array so that all of them will be called. Mixin hooks will be called before the component’s own hooks. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Option-Merging)

See a working example at https://jsfiddle.net/rushimusmaximus/9akf641z/3/

```
Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    console.log("created() in global mixin")
  }
});

const mergeCreatedStrategy = Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created;
Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created = (parent, child) => {
  return mergeCreatedStrategy(parent);
};

new Vue ({
  el: "#vue-app",
  template: '<p>See console output for logging. Rendered at {{renderDate}}</p>',
  data() {
    return {
     renderDate: new Date()
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("created() in component")
  }
})
```