# Vue Test Utils - Skip created hook for a specific test suite

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

[Vue Test Utils - Skip created hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954840/vue-test-utils-skip-created-hook)

there is already a question for this, and that solution works. However, it is skipping the created hook in all my test suites. My code looks like this.

```
describe('test suites', () => {

describe('test suite 1', () => {

test that should not ignore created hook

})

describe('test suite 2', () => {

Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    console.log("created() in global mixin")
  }
});

const mergeCreatedStrategy = Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created;
Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created = (parent, child) => {
  return mergeCreatedStrategy(parent);
};

// This makes it ignore the created hook in test suite 1 as well. I tried to put it in a const 
// like this as well:

  const options = {

    install(Vue) {
      Vue.mixin({
        created() {
        }
      });
      const mergeCreatedStrategy = Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created;
      Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created = (parent, child) => {
        return mergeCreatedStrategy(parent);
      };
    }
  };

  const ignoreCreate = createLocalVue();
  ignoreCreate.use(options);

// and then pass it in the mount options, but still same behaviour for test suite 1.

})

})
```

even using localVue doesnt seem to work. I tried to solve it like this.

```
let localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.mixin({
  created(){}
})
const mergeCreatedStrategy = localVue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created;
localVue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created = (parent, child) => {
  return mergeCreatedStrategy(parent);
};
```

but even without applying the local vue to the mounting options it still ignores the created hook for both the suites.

Even declaring the localVue outside the test suite makes ignore all the created hooks even without applying the localVue.